# how to set python pip to pickup pyhon 3.6

Tags: python, linux, suse

I have to set Python from 2.7 to 3.6 in Suse12 and have set the soft link.
but "pip --version" gives the error "/usr/local/bin/pip"
what do I have to set/configure for pip to pick up the Python 3.6 from the system

Comment: try using `pip3` to call `pip`

Comment: @leun4m: I could see pip2, pip, pip2.7 in /usr/local/bin path

Answer (score 2):

1. Firstly I would suggest try to update pip.
2. If it still shows issues then you can check the pip version associated with Python 3.6 by running `python3.6 -m pip --version`
3. Ensure that the python and pip soft links point to the Python 3.6 versions. If they do not point same you can create soft links like this `ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python`  and `ln -s /usr/bin/pip3.6 /usr/bin/pip`. Please update respective paths if required.
4. Test pip to ensure its using python 3.6  `pip --version`

Comment: which python shows
/usr/bin/python , how to update this to python3.6?

Comment: @Rahul [update-alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272870/how-can-i-change-the-default-python-on-my-ubuntu-20-04-to-python3-8)

Comment: @blackbrandt: I am able to update/choose python to default python3.6

Comment: @Rahul Update the alternatives to set Python 3.6 as the default

Search `sudo update-alternatives` command